# Best approximation of a real number with two functions

Tags: number-theory, functions, real-numbers, approximation-theory

There's two functions, called $F(x)$ and $G(x)$, where $F(x)>x,1<G(x) < x$  ,$F'(x)>0, G'(x)>0$ on $(2,\infty)$, and $F(x),G(x)\in(2,\infty)$. Given $x, y\in (2,\infty)$, and now I want to find the best way to approximate $y$ in finite steps, that is, $F(G(G(F(x)...)))\sim y$.

For example, given $F(x)=\Gamma(x+1),G(x)=\sqrt{x}, x=8, y = 2.2$, and set the maximum steps to $3$. It can be proved that the best approximation is
$$
\sqrt{\Gamma \left(\sqrt{8}+1\right)}=2.20394...
$$

It could be easily done with [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), however I think there should be a faster way to give the result.

Meanwhile, I haven't found any results about the best approximation  (**e.g. the estimation of the error of the best approximation**)

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Do you know anything more about F and G? E.g. are they both strictly increasing?

Comment: Without more info, this problem is not answerable. In particular, if $g(x)=0$, then the problem becomes degenerate.

Comment: Oh yeah they are both increasing. thx

Comment: why $F(x)>x-1$ ?

Comment: well I have just modified the conditions